# Angular + Capacitor: appStateChange listener not working

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

To solve a KPI, i'm trying to generate a logEvent with the Firebase SDK when the user closes the Application (Ionic / Capacitor / Angular). But i'm having a lot of trouble trying to enter at that `appStateChange` listener (That is being created at `ngOnInit` method of my `app.component.ts`).

> As the official Capacitor Background Task Plugin was deactivated, i've been using this community plugin right [here](https://github.com/robingenz/capacitor-background-task), that acts just like the official one

```js
  import { BackgroundTask } from '@robingenz/capacitor-background-task';

  App.addListener('appStateChange', async ({ isActive }) => {
       // It isn't getting here

       if (isActive)
         return;
       
       // When the app is running at the background

       const taskId = await BackgroundTask.beforeExit(async () => {
            console.log('Sending app_close event to Firebase')

            await this.firebaseAnalyticsService.logEvent('app_close', {
              lastScreenName: this.firebaseAnalyticsService.getCurrentScreenName(),
            });

            BackgroundTask.finish({ taskId });
       });
  })
```

i've tried to deal with this by other methods too, with cordova plugins, window.beforeUnload, etc... None of them worked as i was expecting (not entering at the handlers). I would appreciate if someone could help me to figure out this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! My solution was to increase Capacitor versions and remove the background-task plugin, as it was not needed for my intend.